# what is the function of "a foot" in this sentence?

Tags: adjective-phrases, predicative-complement, measure-expressions

"Tsunami waves may appear only **a foot** or so high." 
Does "a foot" function as an adverbial phrase or subject complement?

Answer (score 4):

It is a noun that is part a premodifier in the following phrase:

> *only a foot or so high*

The above phrase in its entirety is the **complement to the subject**. The phrase *only a foot or so* is a **premodifier** for *high*.

Answer (score 2):

The main verb in the sentence is the word *appear*. This verb can take adjective phrases as Complement. In this sentence the adjective phrase is:

- a foot or so **high**

The adjective *high* is the main word in the phrase. In other words, it is the Head of the adjective phrase. This word *high* is being modified by the phrase *a foot or so*. This phrase is a noun phrase. It is a special type of noun phrase called a *MEASURE PHRASE*. We often use measure phrases like this to give further information about an adjective:

- **ten years** old
- **five minutes** long
- **six feet** tall
- **a foot** high

**The Original Poster's Question**

The grammatical function of *foot* is Head of the noun phrase "a foot or so".

The phrase *a foot or so* is a Modifier in the adjective phrase "a foot or so high".

The adjective phrase *a foot or so high* is a Predicative Complement of the verb "*appear*". Because it describes the Subject of the sentence, some writers call it a *Subject* Complement. Books like *A student's introduction to English grammar*, by Huddleston & Pullum (2005) call it an *Subjective* Complement.

Answer (score 0):

"foot" is part of the phrase "only a foot or so high", which Is a subject complement.

Specifically, it is a *predicate adjective* .
-  http://college.cengage.com/devenglish/broughton/focus_florida/1e/students/diagramming/exercise_6.pdf

(The other type of subject complement is a *predicate nominative*)